# Marathon Service Ports

Tags: marathon, dcos

I know that 'servicePort' is used by marathon-lb to identify an app. Is there any other user of this setting besides marathon-lb?
If the answer is no, why is it mandatory (omitting it well generate one for me)? I have many marathon apps which are not managed by marathon-lb, and they all take up service ports by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation: ""servicePort" is a helper port intended for doing service discovery using a well-known port per service. The assigned servicePort value is **not used/interpreted by Marathon itself** but supposed to be used by the load balancer infrastructure."

So service ports seem to have no other use other than for marathon-lb.
When you don't specify a servicePort, its as if you put in "servicePort": 0.
See closed issue [here](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/issues/2521).

[Here's](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/issues/1112) a discussion about the re-architected networking API.

If you look at the [Jira ticket](https://jira.mesosphere.com/browse/MARATHON-4091), you will see that the new API model lets you define services without servicePorts at all.